# Slide Up Window Android

Tags: android

I want to design a UI like the picture below[there is a window hidden at the bottom of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5kFD.png)

there is a window which is at the bottom of the interface. when the user click this window it will slide up like this picture below[slide up the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2jAD.png)

please give me some tutorial or information how I can do this

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: A custom view would do the  trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using android **Bottom Sheet.**

> > A good tutorial can be found [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/).